# Find an element in a stack data structure swift 4

Tags: swift

If found this stack data structure at Ray Wenderlich and it works well:

```
public struct Stack<T> {
  fileprivate var array = [T]()

  public var isEmpty: Bool {
    return array.isEmpty
  }

  public var count: Int {
    return array.count
  }

  public mutating func push(_ element: T) {
    array.append(element)
  }

  public mutating func pop() -> T? {
    return array.popLast()
  }

  public var top: T? {
    return array.last
  }
}
```

I'd like to add another method for finding an element within the stack so that I don't try to add an element more than once. For example, I'm keeping a stack of ViewControllers.

```
var vcStack = Stack<UIViewController>()
vcStack.push(VC1)
vcStack.push(VC2)
```

I'd like to be able to query the Stack and get back a boolean if the input VC exists (or not), like this:

```
if vcStack.hasElement(VC1) {
  //do something
}
```

This is pseudo-code - what would the Swift 4 code be?

```
public var hasElement(_ element: T): -> Bool {
    if array.contains(element){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `if(condition){return true}else{return false}` with `return condition`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your `Stack` class to require that its elements conform to `Equatable`:

```
public struct Stack<T> where T: Equatable {
```

then your `hasElement` would be:

```
public func hasElement(_ element: T) -> Bool {
    return array.contains(element)
}
```

Or you can leave `Stack` declared as you have it, and add `hasElement` to an extension:

```
public extension Stack where T: Equatable {
    public func hasElement(_ element: T) -> Bool {
        return array.contains(element)
    }
}
```

This allows you have to have a Stack of anything but the `hasElement` function will only be available if it's a `Stack` of `Equatable` values.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. (I chose to make the calls Equatable)

Answer (score 0):

struct MenuData {
    let title : String!
    let imageName : String! 
}

class MoreTV: UITableView {

```
var aryMenu : [MenuData] = [MenuData(title: "My Profile".localized, imageName: "ic-user"),]
```

}